# Which partition to modify for Ubuntu dual boot install

Tags: ubuntu, multi-boot

I have read about the partitions before, but I do not fully understand the output command below and wanted to see if anyone can tell me which partition I can resize safely to make room for Ubuntu 18.04 install. I like to have separate `/`, `swap`, and `/home`. I would be happy with 20GB of space. I will backup my hard drive, and you are not responsible in any way if I mess it up. Here is what I see in `fdisk`:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 238.5 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 0FD40AC8-7227-4117-9299-47FBCA209D2D

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048    534527    532480   260M EFI System
/dev/sda2     534528    567295     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda3     567296 403673087 403105792 192.2G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda4  403673088 456101887  52428800    25G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda5  456101888 458149887   2048000  1000M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda6  458149888 498069503  39919616    19G Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda7  498069504 500117503   2048000  1000M Lenovo boot partition
```

- Thanks. I have changed it, and I see it in the partition manager GUI, but I do not seem to find it in the `fdisk` output:

  ```
  Disk /dev/sda: 238.5 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
  Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
  Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
  I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
  Disklabel type: gpt
  Disk identifier: 0FD40AC8-7227-4117-9299-47FBCA209D2D

  Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
  /dev/sda1       2048    534527    532480   260M EFI System
  /dev/sda2     534528    567295     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
  /dev/sda3     567296 403673087 403105792 192.2G Microsoft basic data
  /dev/sda4  403673088 417040275  13367188   6.4G Microsoft basic data
  /dev/sda5  456101888 458149887   2048000  1000M Windows recovery environment
  /dev/sda6  458149888 498069503  39919616    19G Windows recovery environment
  /dev/sda7  498069504 500117503   2048000  1000M Lenovo boot partition
  ```

  [Pic: Ubuntu Partition Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfhIE.png)

  Latest `fdisk` output:

  ```
  Disk /dev/sda: 238.5 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
  Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
  Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
  I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
  Disklabel type: gpt
  Disk identifier: 0FD40AC8-7227-4117-9299-47FBCA209D2D

  Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
  /dev/sda1       2048    534527    532480   260M EFI System
  /dev/sda2     534528    567295     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
  /dev/sda3     567296 403673087 403105792 192.2G Microsoft basic data
  /dev/sda4  403673088 433509025  29835938  14.2G Microsoft basic data
  /dev/sda5  456101888 458149887   2048000  1000M Windows recovery environment
  /dev/sda6  458149888 498069503  39919616    19G Windows recovery environment
  /dev/sda7  498069504 500117503   2048000  1000M Lenovo boot partition
  ```

  [Pic: GParted after the change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCi2B.png)

Here is how my drive looks after successful install of Ubuntu:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 238.5 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 0FD40AC8-7227-4117-9299-47FBCA209D2D

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048    534527    532480   260M EFI System
/dev/sda2     534528    567295     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda3     567296 403673087 403105792 192.2G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda4  403673088 433509025  29835938  14.2G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda5  456101888 458149887   2048000  1000M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda6  458149888 498069503  39919616    19G Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda7  498069504 500117503   2048000  1000M Lenovo boot partition
/dev/sda8  433510400 456067071  22556672  10.8G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda9  456067072 456101887     34816    17M Linux swap
```

Pics: [GParted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqdeZ.png) & [GParted Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFz4m.png)

- Update: Tried to install `ntfs-3g` after updating the repos and it says 
  `ntfs-3g` is already the latest version:

  ```
  ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt update
  Ign:1 ... 
  Fetched 460 kB in 2s (251 kB/s)        
  Reading package lists... Done
  Building dependency tree       
  Reading state information... Done
  270 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.


  ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt install ntfs-3g
  Reading package lists... Done
  Building dependency tree       
  Reading state information... Done
  ntfs-3g is already the newest version (1:2017.3.23-2ubuntu0.18.04.2).
  0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 270 not upgraded.
  ```

Comment: You have conflicting info above... `sda4` is listed in one output as 25GB in size, whereas in the next block it's listed as 6.4GB in size.  Also, just an FYI, if `sda` is a SSD, the OEM appears to have configured your partitions in the wrong way, as SSDs generally need 10% [recommended] of their size reserved at the end of the last partition (`sda7`) for Over Provisioning.  As it stands, `sda` has no space unallocated for OP, which will eventually result in performance issues.

Comment: Yea, I changed it to make room for Ubuntu partition. Oh thank you; I see the result of my change. I guess it is permanent now. I'll try to boot into Windows, and if eveything is ok, I'll come back to the live usb and proceed with the install. btw, what are the options for /, swap, and home in GPARTED, and what sizes should I use now? I guess 10G for /, 10M for swap, and rest home?

Comment: @JW0914-Thank you for your response.

Comment: @JW0914-Hi. Would you respond to my last update please? I do not know why GParted does not let me resize the drive. Can you help?

Comment: I'm not sure how to troubleshoot your issue as I've never encountered this before.  My advice would have been similar to @beauk's advice in his comments below

Answer (score 0):

If you only want 20 GB, then your /dev/sda4 might be a good target.  However, you should probably make sure whatever is on it isn't needed.  It says its 25 GB.

You should also try shrinking your /dev/sda3, the primary data for your Windows install.

Comment: I guess this would be a good time to try to log into Windows and make sure everything is working, and the proceed to partition the free space. If anything is broke, I can go back and return the free space to /dev/sda4. What do you think?

Comment: yes, it would be good to boot into windows before proceeding.  Windows might notice the change and do a quick file system check on itself, which is nothing to be alarmed by.

Comment: @user1110894 Did you verify what partition `sda4` was being used for on Windows?

Comment: Thank you so much. Windows booted fine. I am back now. I did make a stupid mistake and shrank the partition by 200M instead of 20M. But things seem to be working on Windows side. so I am now in Ubuntu usb again, and going to increase the same partition I shrank by 18432M. But the freespace amount has changed; it seems when I boot Winodws, if it needs space and there is freespace it just takes it?

Comment: @user1110894, I'm having a little bit of a hard time following the progression, but it seems like you've ended up with your sda4 as some kind of Windows file system (NTFS,ext4,fat) based on that last fdisk output, and it's about 14.2 gb?  Can you see it from Windows OS, either via Explorer or Disk Management?  If so, and if it's truly empty, you may just want to delete that partition before booting into the USB installer.  Windows will not take free space on a disk, but Ubuntu's installer will probably guide you to install in a free space area by default.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am sorry, I made some mistakes, but everything worked out. I installed it successfully and Windows is working also. I do need to resize and allocate more space to Ubuntu now. :-) I don't think I can use the install usb any more. I guess I need a rescue usb with GParted. Do you know if there is some way I can use my live usb to repartition the drive and not do a fresh Ubuntu install?

Comment: @user1110894 How much free space do you have available on `sda3`, as that's where you're going to have to pull from if you want to use the same 256GB SSD.  For a LiveUSB, simply use the Ubuntu 19 install ISO and Rufus to create the LiveUSB and choose "Try Ubuntu" at the Ubuntu boot window.  You can then install packages, such as `gparted` via a terminal.

Comment: what @JW0914 said :)

Comment: I have about 70G of free space, and I like to pull another 20. Thanks.

Comment: GParted is installed, but when I try to resize /dev/sda3 it does not let me. There is a red exclamation mark next to it. I'll post the image above so you can see it. When I click it, the message says I need ntfs-3g package which I have already. I am not sure what else I can do.

Comment: @user1110894 try `sudo apt update; sudo apt install ntfs-3g` first when you first boot  on the live cd to get support for the ntfs

Comment: @beauk- I did that, and updated my post above. ntfs-3g is already the latest version it says.

Comment: If that sd3 partition is encrypted, that might be an issue.  Do you know if bitlocker is turned on?  If so, you'll probably have a hard time shrinking that, unless you can do it from inside your windows OS, perhaps via the recovery tool. It will have to be a boot environment that can decrypted the data on the partition. I think I've tried that before, so I think it's doable, but I'm sorry, I don't have a quick answer about specifically how to deal with that.

Comment: That is fine. You guys have been more than helpful. Thank you so much. I'll go into bios and see if bitlocker is turned on, and look for procedures to do it from inside Windows. Either way, I was able to get done what I wanted, I just need more room now to do other things. I might just upgrade the hard drive.